# The current path, products/new/, didn't match any of these - Page Not Found

Tags: python, django, error-handling, path

I just installed python 2.2.20 and now when running a Django project I get a page not found error.

[image: My views.py from products app looks like this]

[image: urls.py from products app looks like this]

[image: urls.py from pyshop project looks like this]

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error when I try to navigate to **products/new**
[image: Page not found]

Comment: Did I read that right - `python 2.2.20` ? Please add code snippets as text and not images!

Comment: Your url config has no slash at the end for `new`